# Why is it correct to say “your hair wants cutting”?

Tags: passive-voice

In a multiple choice question:

> Your hair wants ____. You'd better have it done tomorrow.

Clearly here required a passive voice, like "to be cut."
However, the answer given is "cutting." Why is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Wants to be cut" would sound like a desire on the part of your hair.  Where "want" means "need", the present participle is usual.  So "cutting" is correct.  (Note: Dictionaries label this use of "want" as British.)

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/want) has this:

> **want** *verb* [T] (NEED) *UK* to need something:
> Do you think this soup wants a bit of salt?
> *[ + -ing verb ]* The wine is in the fridge - it just wants cooling for a couple of minutes.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/want) has this:

> *British with present participle* (of a thing) require to be attended to in a specified way.
> ‘the wheel wants greasing’
> ‘The whole lot wants digging up and replacing with a small roundabout like it should have been since day one.’

Comment: But using "cutting" sounds like an active voice instead of a passive voice

Comment: @HypnoticBuggyWraithVirileBevy "Cutting" doesn't have a voice here - it is acting as a quasi-noun, as randomhead suggested.  I agree that "wants" is active.  You could think of "wants cutting" as meaning "requires a cut(ting)" (although "a cutting" would be very unidiomatic here).  However, ultimately, "why" questions aren't easy to answer.

Comment: so I could also say "my hair wants washing," or any other gerund after "want"? I feel it's a bit strange

Comment: @HypnoticBuggyWraithVirileBevy  Yes.  It is a somewhat informal usage (a technical manual wouldn't say "The device wants connecting"!).  It may be commoner with some verbs (it's certainly quite common and idiomatic with "washing" and "cutting") but can be used with others too (as shown in the examples given by Cambridge and Lexico).

Comment: So what's the more formal expression of the same meaning?

Comment: "Needs to be cut/washed/etc".

Answer (score 0):

In modern English we would not use the phrase "wants [infinitive]." We would probably use the phrase "needs [infinitive]" or "needs [verbal noun-ing]," as in "You hair needs to be cut" or "Your hair needs cutting." You are correct that we use the passive voice, but *wanting* is an active thing, so "wants [infinitive]" sounds strange.

But some people do use the phrase "wants [verbal noun-ing]," which is an archaic construction. This usage is Definition 5 at [wiktionary.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/want#English)

In Pittsburgh dialect especially, people use the ["needs [verb]" construction,](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/needs-washed) using the infinitive but dropping "to be." This is local dialect and would not be used in written communication.

Comment: Isn't the Pittsburgh construction "needs" plus past participle, rather than "needs" plus infinitive? Or are you calling it the infinitive because you assume there's an implicit "to be"?

Comment: I don't agree that "wants cutting" is an archaic construction. It's certainly very common in the UK. And Wiktionary doesn't label sense 5 archaic. ("From 15c" means that it was first attested then, not that it has fallen into disuse since.)

Comment: @rjpond good points both. I refer to the PGH construction as using the infinitive because the article mentions that the correct phrase is "needs to be cut" and the "to be" is dropped.

Comment: " but wanting is an active thing, so "wants [infinitive]" sounds strange." what do u mean by that?